# What is the best way to update a list attribute in my model using Entity Framework?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, model-view-controller

My model looks like this:

```
public class Parent
{
  public int Id {get; set;}
  public virtual List<Child> Children {get; set;}
}

public class Child
{
  public int Id {get; set;}
  public int age {get; set;}
}
```

Now I want to edit a parent and change the children from `c1, c2` to `c2, c3`. I am currently using checkboxes in my View to achieve this. However, the results never reflect in the database. I think it is because of the foreign key constraints that EF is creating. (Yes, I do have the `db.Entry(role).State = EntityState.Modified;` line in my controller.)

I don't know how best to achieve this. Do I create a new parent everytime? Or do I manually delete each child that is not selected from the parent's children? Or do I just create a new list of children everytime I want to update? Or maybe something cleaner?

Edit: Added controller code

```
    public ActionResult Edit(ViewModel model, String[] selectedChildren)
    {
        var parent= db.Parent.FirstOrDefault(r => r.Id== model.Parent.Id);

        //Delete any child from parent that is not in selected children  
        foreach (var child in selectedChildren)
        {
            if (!(Parent.Children.Contains(child)))
            {
                parent.Children.Remove(child);
            }
        }

        foreach (var s in selectedChildren)
        {
            var child = db.Children
                .FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id == s);
            parent.Children.Add(child);
        }

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Entry(parent).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(model);
    }
```

Comment: can you add the controller code where the update is done?

Comment: @dellywheel added controller code.

Comment: thx controller code looks ok. I would put a try catch around `db.SaveChanges();` and look out for a `DbUpdateException`